# Confuse about String Interpolation in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have this code where this inline variable `{ (hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM") }`

I create it and it works but I am confused because without the braces `()` I have some issue with code lots of red underlines there,  infect compiler code suggestions refactor it with red underlines but after wrap my expression with `()` it works.

I just want to know what is status of `()` in this interpolation inline variable?

```
WriteLine($"{hour}:{minout}:{seconds} { (hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM") }");
```

Comment: Just to make sure that you provide an example, but don't use this code really this way - `dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")` is the right way to do this. P.S. `12:00` is 12 PM, not 12 AM.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i just create it for demo purpose. Just for learning some C# 6 and c# 7 features. Thanks i will use your suggestion in my projects. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`:` operator is valid operator for string formatting which used in string interpolation

```
var date = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
var stringDate = $"Date is {date:yyyy.MM.dd}"; // "Date is 2017.08.31"
```

Without parenthesis `:` is considered as format string, but not conditional operator, so for using conditional operator you should wrap your conditional expression with parenthesis.

```
var stringDate = $"It is {(date.Hours > 12 ? "evening" : "morning")}";
```

Another approach (perhaps more readable) execute all expressions before formatting result

```
var dayPart = date.Hours > 12 ? "evening" : "morning";
var stringDate = $"It is {dayPart}";
```

Comment: I never understood why they allowed expression in there. I mean if you need it again later you need to copy paste your code. While using a computed variable (like in your second approach) makes it reusable at least plus it's much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses there denote an expression, whose evaluation is required first and then its outcome is that would be the input of the interpolated string.

For a formal approach please have a look at the following link

[Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions) and search for the term *Parenthesized expressions*
 in this document.

Regarding the interpolated strings, you can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). However the one thing that you have to keep in mind is it's structure:

```
$"<text> {<interpolated-expression> [,<field-width>] [<:format-string>] } <text> ..."
```

In your case the `(...)` is the interpolated-expression.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But why code suggestion not refactor correct way.

Comment: @BabarQB You are welcome. To the extent that I am aware of about refactor suggestions, I could say that the compiler can't suggest you all the possible ways you can refactor your code. Certainly, it can spot many common patterns and then make you a suggestion. However, there are plenty of other patterns for which you will not get from any compiler / or any static analysis tool a suggestion for refactoring.